# PageView widget in vertical wrapped in Scrollbar Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to implement a list of image arranged in a column vertically. I used `PageView` Widget to make use of the `PageChange` listener to indicate what current page I currently am. However I am implementing this in WebView as well so I need to wrap it in `ScrollBar`. Although the `Scrollbar` is showing and moving accordingly, it is not draggable or not automatically scrolling if I used the `ScrollBar`. Is theres a work around this or a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `controller` for the `Scrollbar` widget with the same `controller` of `PageView` widget.

- Define a PageController

  - ```dart
    final PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    ```
- Pass the `pageController` to the `controller` property of `Scrollbar` widget.

  - ```dart
    return Scrollbar(
       controller: pageController,
       isAlwaysShown: true, // This forces the scrollbar to be visible always
       child: PageView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         controller: pageController,
    ```

You can set other properties like `thickness` and `hoverthickness` to addjust the thickness of the scroll bar. Refer this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbkIQSvwnZc) and [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html) for more details.

A working demo. Also available as a dartpad [here](https://dartpad.dev/312bdcdc6a6e9c70e33f5dd57467d4cb?null_safety=true):

```dart
/// Flutter code sample for PageView

// Here is an example of [PageView]. It creates a centered [Text] in each of the three pages
// which scroll horizontally.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: pageController,
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 10,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      hoverThickness: 15,
      radius: Radius.circular(0),
      child: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: pageController,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text('First Page'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Second Page'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Third Page'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Kudos to you! Thank you you saved me! Keep safe!